# How to import this JSON data into a postgresql table?

Tags: json, postgresql, import, jsonb, postgresql-13

i have the following JSON:

```json
{
   "ticket":{
      "ticket":"61086762bb68d90001148fe9",
      "timestamp":"2021-08-02T18:45:06.581-0300"
   },
   "serie":{
      "measurement":{
         "nemo":"RT",
         "description":"Real Time"
      },
      "tagSet":{
         "Granularity":"1h",
         "Facility":"382"
      },
      "fieldSet":{
         "EnvTemperature":"°C",
         "HorizIrrad":"W/m²"
      }
   },
   "values":[
      {
         "tagSet":{
            "Facility":"382",
            "Granularity":"1h"
         },
         "fieldSet":{
            "EnvTemperature":7.0,
            "HorizIrrad":632.0
         },
         "time":"2021-08-02T11:00:00.000-0300"
      },
      {
         "tagSet":{
            "Facility":"382",
            "Granularity":"1h"
         },
         "fieldSet":{
            "EnvTemperature":10.0,
            "HorizIrrad":884.0
         },
         "time":"2021-08-02T12:00:00.000-0300"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to know how could i import "EnvTemperature", "HorizIrrad" and "time" from the section "values" into a table like this:

| time | EnvTemperature | HorizIrrad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-02 11:00:00 | 7 | 632 |
| 2021-08-02 12:00:00 | 10 | 884 |

or like this:

| time | Fieldset | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-02 11:00:00 | EnvTemperature | 7 |
| 2021-08-02 11:00:00 | HorizIrrad | 632 |
| 2021-08-02 12:00:00 | EnvTemperature | 10 |
| 2021-08-02 12:00:00 | HorizIrrad | 884 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)` that returns all json array elements as `value`.

```
select 
    (value->>'time')::timestamp as "time",
    (value->'fieldSet'->>'EnvTemperature')::numeric as "EnvTemperature",
    (value->'fieldSet'->>'HorizIrrad')::numeric as "HorizIrrad"
from the_data
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_col->'values')
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cdbf3a2c360374646ccb11d76a1ee72f)

Read about [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)